# Grep rows from top command based on a condition

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

```
[xxxxx@xxxx3 ~]$ top
top - 16:29:00 up 197 days, 19:06, 12 users,  load average: 19.16, 21.08, 21.58
Tasks: 3668 total,  21 running, 3646 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 14.1%us,  6.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 79.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  264389504k total, 53305000k used, 211084504k free,   859908k buffers
Swap: 134217720k total,   194124k used, 134023596k free, 12854016k cached

   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 19938 jai_web  20   0 3089m 2.9g 7688 R 100.0  1.1   0:10.26 Engine
 19943 jai_web  20   0 3089m 2.9g 7700 R 100.0  1.1   0:10.14 Engine
 20147 jai_web  20   0  610m 454m 3556 R 78.4  0.2   0:02.54  java
 77169 jai_web  20   0 9414m 1.4g  29m S 21.3  0.6  38:51.69  java
 20160 jai_web  20   0  362m 196m 3336 R 16.7  0.1   0:00.54  java
272287 jai_web  20   0 20.1g 2.0g 5784 S 15.1  0.8 165:39.50  java
 26597 jai_web  20   0 6371m 134m 3444 S  9.6  0.1 429:41.97  java
```

From the snippet of top command above i want to grep PIDs which have Value of TIME+ greater than 10:00:00 that belongs to 'java' process

so am expecting grep output as below:

```
 77169 jai_web  20   0 9414m 1.4g  29m S 21.3  0.6  **38:51.69** java
272287 jai_web  20   0 20.1g 2.0g 5784 S 15.1  0.8 **165:39.58** java
 26597 jai_web  20   0 6371m 134m 3444 S  9.6  0.1 **429:41.97** java
```

i have tried below:

```
top -p "$(pgrep -d ',' java)"
```

But doesnt satisfies my condition.Please assist

Comment: Start with: **top | grep java**. I'll see for the condition...

Answer (score 2):

I would just do this for one time analysis.

```
$ top -n 1 -b | awk '$NF=="java" && $(NF-1) >= "10:00.00"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I came up with...

You need to get the output of top, filter only the java lines, then check each line to see if the TIME is bigger than your limit.  Here is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
tmpfile="/tmp/top.output"

top -o TIME -n 1 | grep java >$tmpfile

# filter each line and keep only the ones where TIME is bigger than a certain value
limit=10
while read line
do
    # take the line and keep only the 11th field, which is the time value
    # In that time value, keep only the first number
    timevalue=$(echo $line | awk '{print $12}' | cut -d':' -f1)

    # compare timevalue to the limit we set
    if [ $timevalue -gt $limit ]
    then
        # output the entire line
        echo $line
    fi
done <$tmpfile

# cleanup
rm -f /tmp/top.output
```

The trick here is to extract the TIME value, only the first digits.  The other digits are not significant, as long as the first is bigger than 10.

Someone might know of a way to do it via grep, but I doubt it, I have never seen conditionals in grep.

Comment: `awk '$NF=="java" && $(NF-1) >= "10:00:00"'` should do

Comment: Hi @karakfa could you help me with full condition how i can use the above awk in conjuction with TOP?